# Should these two questions be merged?

Tags: discussion

Justkt merged the question [When should I use passive voice?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2325/when-should-i-use-passive-voice) with the question [When should I avoid passive voice?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/523/when-should-i-avoid-the-passive-voice-when-might-i-use-it) I don't believe these questions should've been merged. The first question asked how to avoid passive voice. The second asked when is it acceptable to use passive voice. The first question was asked and answered back in November. The question already has an accepted answer to the original question. It doesn't seem right to edit the question months after it was answered to add a new, separate question to it. Both of these questions should be separate since they're asking two different things, IMO.

Comment: Thank you! I posed the "When should I" question and was surprised at it being merged. I couldn't figure out how to comment on it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I unmerged them and re-opened the question.

Let's have a do-over on this one.